# Почему прописывается array в параметрах функции?

Tags: php, функции

```
<?php
  $message = "Работа не может быть продолжена из-за ошибок:<br />";
  $check = function(array $errors) use ($message)
  {
    if (isset($errors) && count($errors) > 0) {
      echo $message;
      foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo "$error<br />";
      }
    }
  };
  $check([]);
  $erorrs[] = "Заполните имя пользователя";
  $check($erorrs);
  $message = "Список требований"; 
  $erorrs = ["PHP", "MySQL", "memcache"];
  $check($erorrs);
?>
```

И что значит `$check([])`?

Answer (score 1):

`$check([])` это вызов функции для проверки на ошибки.

Проверка идет в строке `if (isset($errors) && count($errors) > 0) {` вот а сама функция выдаст ошибку вызова если ее не будет.

Можно было написать `$check = function(array $errors = []) use ($message)`, что задало бы дефолтное значение.